# Выбрать из списка конкретные данные

Tags: python-3.x

Существует список:

```
[<div class="cell">
<a href="/url1/">
<img alt="img" src="catalog" title="Title1"/>
</a>
</div>,
<div class="cell">
<a href="/url2/">
<img alt="img2" src="catalog" title="Title2"/>
</a>
</div>]
```

Список переполнен лишними тегами, а нужны только тэги 'a'. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать. Как очистить список от других тэгов или выбрать тэги 'a' включить в отдельный список. Спасибо!

Comment: Это точно строка? Выглядит как список списков строк. Впрочем кавычки расставлены так, что это вообще синтаксически неправильная конструкция.

Comment: Да, мой пример был некорректный. Я исправил.

Comment: @I.Z., как вы получили этот список? Есть подозрение, что проще будет правильно распарсить исходный HTML...

Comment: Да вот в этом и "затык". Проще всего (меньше тэгов на выходе) получается в моем примере, иначе, тэгов 'а' еще больше.

Comment: @I.Z., лучше [приведите в вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/946681/edit) небольшой но воспроизводимый кусок HTML и пример того что вы хотите получить на выходе...

Comment: Парсить HTML регулярками - очень неблагодарная работа. Лучше, проще и быстрее воспользоваться одним из готовых HTML парсеров

Comment: Такой список не может существовать, т.к. тут неправильный синтаксис.